# Implementing ChatGPT plugins in a custom GPT-4-based application

Tags: plugins, openai-api

I am working on a custom GPT-4-based application, and I would like to provide the model with "memory" by implementing a retrieval mechanism similar to the ones used in ChatGPT plugins. After extensive research on prompting mechanisms and ChatGPT plugin documentation, I understand that plugins are designed for the ChatGPT API, but I would like to incorporate a similar mechanism in my custom application.

Could someone guide me on how to create a retrieval mechanism for a GPT-4-based application that uses the OpenAI API? My goal is to maintain a consistent JSON interface for prompting and leverage any best practices or fine-tuning that has been established around the plugin approach.

Here's what I have researched so far:

1. GPT-4's architecture and its capabilities.
2. OpenAI API documentation to understand the interaction with the model.
3. ChatGPT plugins and their use cases.
4. the documentation for the chatgpt-retrieval-plugin

I am seeking advice on the most effective way to adapt plugin-like functionality to my custom application. Any suggestions on how to proceed or examples of similar implementations would be greatly appreciated.

My current approach is to try to repurpose the plugin to a custom application environment.    GPT4 itself is doing a decent job of helping me through this, but I thought a real human might have a better approach or some ideas on how to get the model to consistently interface to external data sources as is the goal of plugins in general.

Answer (score 1):

About adding plugins through API, I do not know about that. But what I can help you about is adding retrieval augmented generation (RAG) to ChatGPT, using embeddings. Does [this](https://github.com/openai/openai-cookbook/blob/main/examples/Question_answering_using_embeddings.ipynb) answer your question?